# WordPress: Change admin wp_editor background color?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, wp-editor

I'd like my user to be able to dynamically set the background color of the wp_editor on the Edit Page screen.

For example, I'm using the Iris color picker to let the user set a background color for their page.

I'd like this color to be applied to the visual editor as they are editing, so they will see what it looks like.

As a test, I tried modifying the editor's background color by calling:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    content_style: "div { background-color: #000000; }",
});
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I needed to do was this:

```
tinyMCE.get(0).getBody().style.backgroundColor = color;
```

I'm using WordPress' built-in [Iris Color Picker](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/). Here's the full call:

```
$('.colorpicker').iris({
    change: function(event,ui){
        tinyMCE.get(0).getBody().style.backgroundColor = ui.color.toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: tinyMCE.get(0).getBody().style.backgroundColor 
this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The `content_style` setting works on elements inside the "body" of the HTML document in TinyMCE  - what you really want to do is make the background of the `<body>` a different color.

To do this look at the `content_css` setting for the init:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  content_css : "CSS/content.css"
});
```

This allows you to load an external CSS file for use inside TinyMCE.  Then in the content.css file you can do something like this:

```
body {
  .
  .
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Now the background color of the editor itself will be gray (based on the above example).

If you use `content_css` you really don't need `content_style` as you can put all of your CSS in the external CSS file.

**EDIT:**

If `content_css` does not work, you could try using the onInit event and update the CSS:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
        editor.getBody().style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF66";
    });
  ...
})
```

...which results in this:

[image]

(note that I just added this via the console to show that it can be done)

You would need a way to pass that color into the configuration object (a JS variable would work) but this should also get the job done.

Comment: The background color needs to be dynamic, so relying on a predefined style sheet won't work. Since the user selects from a color picker, the background would need to be any number of colors.

Comment: @HWD - please see my edit.  Perhaps that would work for your use case?

Comment: This seems to change the background color of the excerpt textarea, not the primary text area. How do I target that instead?

Comment: So do you have a custom page template?  What is the "excerpt" `textarea` vs the "primary" `textarea`?  If you have multiple TinyMCE instances on the page how are you defining the configuration for each one?  When I use that code in my init the body of the editor turns yellow as I expect but the default page template has one single TinyMCE editor. (see screenshot above)

Comment: I'm using the standard Edit Page like you are in the example, except for that I have excerpts enabled, so there is a textarea for excerpts as well. When I use your script, it initiates TinyMCE on that text box instead of updating the one that is already there.